# Maximum permit count exceeded : Semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

```
public class semaphoreTest {

static LinkedList<Integer> integerLinkedList = new LinkedList<>();
static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
static Object lock = new Object();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                produce();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                consume();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

}


private static void produce() throws InterruptedException {
    semaphore.acquire();
    int value = 0;
    while (true) {
        while (integerLinkedList.size() == 10) {
            semaphore.release();
        }

        integerLinkedList.add(value++);


    }

}

private static void consume() throws InterruptedException {
    semaphore.acquire();
    while (true) {
        while (integerLinkedList.size() == 0) {
            semaphore.release();
        }
        //semaphore.release();
        Integer value = integerLinkedList.removeFirst();
        System.out.println("Size of the List is " + integerLinkedList.size() + " and value removed is " + value);
        semaphore.release();

        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}


}
```

This is the producer consumer problem I am trying to write using semaphore as lock. but I cannot figure out after almost removing 240 elements approx it gives an error message as `Maximum permit count exceeded`.

I am releasing the locks at the correct place but cannot figure out what is wrong in the acquiring part of it.

The error message is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.Error: Maximum permit count exceeded
at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore$Sync.tryReleaseShared(Semaphore.java:192)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.releaseShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1341)
at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.release(Semaphore.java:426)
at interviewQuestions.semaphoreTest.procude(semaphoreTest.java:53)
at interviewQuestions.semaphoreTest.access$000(semaphoreTest.java:12)
at interviewQuestions.semaphoreTest$1.run(semaphoreTest.java:23)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.Error: Maximum permit count exceeded
at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore$Sync.tryReleaseShared(Semaphore.java:192)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.releaseShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1341)
at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.release(Semaphore.java:426)
at interviewQuestions.semaphoreTest.consume(semaphoreTest.java:72)
at interviewQuestions.semaphoreTest.access$100(semaphoreTest.java:12)
at interviewQuestions.semaphoreTest$2.run(semaphoreTest.java:33)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though @Supun answer is correct, but I needed the thread to run indefinitely. Hence I figured out the solution.

```
public void produces() throws InterruptedException {

    int value = 0;
    while (true){
        semaphore.acquire();
        if(integerList.size() != 10 ) {
            integerList.add(value++);
        }
        semaphore.release();
    }

}

public void consumes() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(100);
    semaphore.acquire();
    while (true){
        Integer take = integerList.removeFirst();
        System.out.println("Size of the BlockingQueue is : "+ integerList.size()+" and the value consumed is :"+take);
        Thread.sleep(100);
        semaphore.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Actually my solution runs infinitely. I had made a small mistake that I had mentioned break; instead of continue; .  You can see that while(true) is there which is supposed to run infinitely. :)) I like your produce() method since it's much simple. but your consume() method seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is ***you release your semaphore more times than acquired***. You should remove *`while`* to release your semaphore. You should only release once, so use *`if`* instead.

And according to your program `produce()` and `consume()` should change into this.

***produce()***

```
private static void produce() throws InterruptedException {       
    int value = 0;      

    while (true) {
        //try to get control & put an item.
        semaphore.acquire();

        //but if the queue is full, give up and try again.
        if (integerLinkedList.size() == 10) {
            semaphore.release();
            continue;
        }

        //if not full, put an item & release the control.
        integerLinkedList.add(value++);
        semaphore.release();

    }

}
```

***consume()***

```
private static void consume() throws InterruptedException {        
    while (true) {
        //try to get the control and consume an item.
        semaphore.acquire();

        //but if the queue is empty, give up and try again.
        if (integerLinkedList.size() == 0) {
            semaphore.release();
            continue;
        }

        //if not empty, *consume first one, *print it, *release the control and go sleep.
        Integer value = integerLinkedList.removeFirst();
        System.out.println("Size of the List is " + integerLinkedList.size() + " and value removed is " + value);

        semaphore.release();    
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

if you wish to be in more safer side you can put some thing like `Thread.sleep(50);` before each `break;` statements, so that you are giving some time for the other thread to continue its execution.

I assumed that you program the typical producer consumer problem. If you want me to change something, please let me know. Anyway hope this sorts out your basic problem. :))